# iPhone Simulator on Macbook is showing question Mark

Tags: macbook-pro, iphone, xcode-simulator

iPhone Simulator on Macbook is showing question Mark. I am not able to launch the iPhone Simulator. I have my app deployed on the simulator.

How to fix the iPhone Simulator?

Comment: It'd be good to have more details, such as what version of Xcode you're running, what iOS simulator you're trying to use, what steps you're doing to try and launch it, and what you've already tried to get it to work?

Answer (score -1):

Try to open it from `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Applications/Simulator.app`